# WSO2 API Manager - Error when Posting to service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I attempt to do a POST to a REST service that consumes and produces JSON I get the following error

> ```
> <HTML><HEAD>
> <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
> </HEAD><BODY>
> <H1>Bad Request</H1>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
> Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;ede33f17&#46;1367550275&#46;14409f75
> </BODY>
> </HTML>
> ```

I am able to run a get (with Authentication turned off) however, POSTS are not working.

Answer (score 1):

What is the REST client you used to post the messages to service? Also check whether you have set 'Accept: application/json' and 'Content-type: application/json' headers in your request message.

Comment: Hi sharaPremadasa I am using REST Console for Chrome. Yes, the two headers are set that way. Initially i was getting a null pointer exception when I post without a payload (some of our mapped services have no payload for post) but when there is a payload then I get the above.

Comment: Have you set the Authentication header as "Authorization: Bearer <API Key>" too? May be this doc would help. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM120/Testing+an+API

Comment: That is set correctly. I will read through the document you advise and ensure I am following it to the letter. I'll post back my results here when complete.

Comment: I am getting a 411 Length Required Error when I post, I didn't notice this before.